# Can "Subject Verb+ing" act as a singular noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, gerunds

Let me provide an example sentence:

> Children telling lies prevent/prevents adults from helping them in the most appropriate way.

"Children telling lies"  is "Subject Verb+ing". Can this as a whole act as a singular noun? I see it as one situation. This situation prevents adults from helping them in the most appropriate way.

Comment: No: grammatically, "children telling lies" is not a noun but a noun phrase functioning as subject. The head of the NP is the plural noun "children" which is modified by the clause "telling lies". Semantically, you can consider it a single situation if you like.

Comment: Yes, and for what it's worth, plural "prevent" is correct too. If plural, it means, "*Children **who are** telling lies **prevent** adults from...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

If it were the children themselves who prevented adults from doing something, the verb would be plural.

But if it is the action of the children (in telling lies), the verb is singular.

Similar examples might be:

> Beggars threatening passers-by is a curse in the town.
>
> Teachers failing to prepare lessons is now a common problem in schools.

This makes it clear that the issue is not the beggars or teachers themselves, but their problematic behaviour.

The same logic applies to your example.

Comment: The comment on the question posted by @BillJ is correct; this is not a case where the singular should be used. The subject of each of these sentences is a noun _phrase_ rather than a noun; the conjugation of the verb should follow the noun from the phrase - that is, the nouns are, respectively, "Beggars" and "Teachers", both of which are plural. You are correct, idiomatically, that it is the behavior that is the problem, but taking it out of idiomatic usage, you are really saying that the problem is the specific class "people who are engaging in the behavior". _more..._

Comment: ..._more_. In the querent's original example, the problem is that someone/something is preventing the adults from helping; that someone/something is the class of "children [who are] telling lies" - a plural subject in a noun phrase. Thus, the use of the plural form of the verb is correct - _Children telling lies **prevent** adults from helping them..._.

Comment: You could also argue that it's the phenomenon or fact, singular, of children telling lies that the sentence refers to. I can replace "children telling lies" with "it", and then the verb must be singular: "Children telling lies is a common problem. It prevents teachers from..."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin How about: **Dogs sharing the bed is not to be recommended** and **Dogs sharing the bed are not to be recommended.**. The two sentences mean completely different things. And both are valid. So is: **Men slaving in the sun is the image I retained**. Numerous other examples could be found where the singular verb is legitimate, calling your ruling into doubt.

Comment: @user8356 - But in the original sentence, it's _prevents teachers from helping **them**_ - that is, prevents the teachers from helping the children [{who are} telling lies]. Breaking the sentence into two as you propose produces a situation where the subject of the first sentence is presumed singular, but the antecedent of the second sentence - which is presumed to be the subject of the first - is presumed plural. You can't have it both ways; the subject of the first sentence cannot be simultaneously singular and plural in number.

Comment: @RonaldSole - You do have a good point; but try rephrasing the sentence to express what you mean without having questionable verb conjugation: Your first one implicitly says "Allowing a dog to sleep with in a bed with a person is not to be recommended"; your second one implicitly says "One should not have a dog that sleeps in a bed with a person (but having a dog that sleeps in his own basket is fine)". _more..._

Comment: _...more_ In the case of the _slaving in the sun_ sentence, this can be broken up into two sentences that makes the singular use of the verb correct, and the subject is **not** _Men slaving in the sun_ - rather, the subject is _the image_: _I retained an image. The image was of men slaving in the sun._ Suppose I had retained several distinct images, each of a man slaving (alone) in the sun - then, it would be correct to say _Men slaving in the sun are the images I retained._ Note that the conjugation of the verb follows the number of _image/images_, not that of _Men_.